# Placing an image in the middle of a div AND resize it when the window gets too small

Tags: html, css, image, center

I have an image that needs to be placed in the middle of a div that has max-width: 700px;

When the window is narrowed and the div gets smaller than the width of the image it contains, I want the image to get smaller as well.

In the following fiddle I added both functions separately: https://jsfiddle.net/rb1hyxh2/ but I cannot find a way to combine them (e.g. margin: 0 auto; does not work with the inline-block here...)

```
<div class="header1"><div class="header2">
    <img src="http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" class="header3">
</div></div>

<div class="header1">
    <img src="http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" class="headerA">
</div>


.header1{
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: red;  
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.header2{
    background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
.header3{
    width: 100%;
}

.headerA{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to set **max-width** on headerA to the width of the image and give it a **width** of 100%. That way it will fill up the size of the div when the div is smaller than 500px.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXxNbw)

**HTML**

```
<div class="header1">
  <img src="http://wp.patheos.com.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/faithwalkers/files/2013/03/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" class="headerA" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header1 {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.headerA {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Added lines in **CSS**

```
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The problem is that I use this code for multiple image, all with a different width..

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
img {
  width: 100%; /* or any other value < 100% will stay within bounds */
}
```

to your css file, then your images stay within the bounds of the red colored div's that you have. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: In this case the image can also get bigger than it originally is, which is unfortunately not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javscript version to set all images with the class `.headerA` to a max width of their original width, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rb1hyxh2/5/

```
<script>
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.headerA');
for (var i = 0, element; element = imgs[i]; i++) {
        var w = imgs[i].naturalWidth;
    imgs[i].style.maxWidth = w+"px";
}
</script>
```

I think this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/rb1hyxh2/3/

I added `width: 100%;` and `max-width: 500px;` to the image, this will set the img to 100% of the div but not when the div is greater then 500px;

```
.headerA {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The problem is that I use this code for multiple image, all with a different width..

Comment: Yes, I have already looked for one myself but was not able to find it.

Comment: @Jip look at my new fiddle in my answer this should do it for you.

Comment: @ Adam thanks a lot, that is exactly what I am looking for. However for some reason it does not work on my site. The javascript function does not affect the image (the image gets the max-width = 700px of the div it is in). I do not get how this is possible, since the jsfiddle is perfectly working. Do you have any idea? Am have tried to solve it for 1 hour but nothing seems to work..

Comment: @Jip I would check all your css to make sure there is nothing overriding it, also make sure you have a link to the JQuery

Comment: the problem was that I placed the javascript in an external javascript file while it seems the javascript needs to be placed AFTER the images it affects.. 
Next to this, when the page is loaded for the first time the images will not be visible. Only after a second load they will appear. Do you have an idea how this can be solved?

Comment: @Jip it would be best to close this question, since this answer solves that problem. Then open another question with the code so that we can see it, I will watch for the question and try to help you out, it is just too hard to figure out through comments.

Comment: @ Adam the problem as descibed above also holds for your jsfiddle: when you open that jsfiddle for the first time (you can try it with a new browser, I did so and also with multiple pcs) than the first time the images will not appear. Only after loading the page again / running it again, the images will show up. As if the javascript cannot affect the images at first.

Comment: @Jip did you try this new fiddle?